# winmerge how to use line filters

Tags: regex, winmerge

I have two text files, some lines starting with a forward slash (/). I want those lines to be ignored. Line filters are definitely enabled, and I've tried `^/` and `^\/` with no luck. I even tried to use `^.*$` to try and ignore all differences, and that didn't work. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Silly me, there is a check box next to the line filter. So when you add a line filter, it doesn't automatically default to be on. You have to manually apply it.